# How to change the name of an image that is generated by CodeIgniter Captcha?

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

I am using CodeIgniter Captcha Helper to generate captcha images for my website. It is working perfectly fine. But the only problem is that it generates a random name for the captcha image. How can I change the name of the image that is generated by CodeIgniter Captcha Helper? I have used the following code for generating my captcha.

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
$keyword = $this->generate_random_keyword();
$vals = array(
    'word'  => $keyword,
    'img_path'     => './captcha/',
    'img_url'     => base_url() . '/captcha/',
    'img_width'     => '150',
    'img_height' => '35',
    'border' => 0, 
    'font_path'  => './fonts/texb.ttf',
    'expiration' => 3600
);
$captcha = create_captcha($vals);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CodeIgniter/system/helpers/captcha_helper.php` line 231

```
$img_name = $now.'.jpg';
```

You can modify it directly (probably not a good idea as updates may overwrite). Or you could create your own helper by copying the original, modifying and putting it in `application/helpers`.

If you want to customize the name via parameter, something like this should do it:

```
// line 42
function create_captcha($data = '', $img_path = '', $img_url = '', $font_path = '', $captcha_filename = '')
```

then

```
// line 231
if ($captcha_filename != '')
{
    $img_name = $captcha_filename.'.jpg';
}
else
{
    $img_name = $now.'.jpg';
}
```

Be aware, though, that this example may overwrite existing captcha's in the same directory if you set `$captcha_filename`.

So, copy `captcha_helper.php` into `application/helpers`, make the changes on line 42 and 231 (or just 231), save, and you should be good.